How to disable cmd+shift+. on MacOS?
How do I disable cmd+shift+. shortcut on MacOS?
I don't see it listed under the keyboard section on system preferences.
The shortcut is used to show hidden apps on your mac.
I want to disable it because I keep deleting my website/app blocker whenever I lose control.

What does Cmd-Shift-. do on your Mac?

Why do you want to disable it in the first place?

@nohillside It toggles visibility of hidden files in Finder. Works in open/save dialogs too, which can be handy.

@luckman212 Indeed. Let's see whether the OP comes back with details.

Your ad blocker is installed as a hidden file/folder? Disabling cmd-shift-. will not stop you from removing it (I can think of several alternatives).

I would imagine Karabiner-Elements might allow you to remap that combo to a null action.

@nohillside please let me know what I can do instead. The website blocker is not installed as a hidden file. I hide the application file under the Application Support folder using Terminal and then block Terminal. (Deleting the file would delete any record of the blocks).

On Karabiner-Elements will the code then be {
"type": "basic",
"from": {
"key_code": ".",
"modifiers": {
"mandatory": ["command"],
"mandatory": ["shift"]
}
},
"conditions": [
{
"type": "frontmost_application_if",
"bundle_identifiers": ["^com\.apple\.finder$"]
}
]
}

You can use Karabiner-Elements to do this. I just tested it with macOS 14.4.1 + KBE 14.13.0 and it worked for me.
Add a Custom Rule under Complex Modifications:

And use the JSON below e.g.
{
  "description": "Disable Cmd+Shift+[.] shortcut in Finder",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "conditions": [
        {
          "bundle_identifiers": [
            "^com.apple.finder"
          ],
          "type": "frontmost_application_if"
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "key_code": "period",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
            "command",
            "shift"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "vk_none"
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}



thank you for the solution!

@meh Glad it worked for you. Please mark it as an accepted answer if you consider it solved.
